# How to tcpreplay only packets satisfying a pcap filter rule?

Tags: tcpdump, tcpreplay

I have a dump file with lots of various packets in it, but I want to selectively replay, say, only all udp packets to a given port number, without having to edit the dump file first.

How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tcpdump` can do the filtering and its result then be piped to `tcpreplay`.

```
tcpdump -r dump.pcap -w- 'udp port 1234' | tcpreplay -ieth0 -
```